# Unix Output of command to text file

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I'm reading from a file called IMSI.txt using the following command:

```
$awk 'NR>2' IMSI.txt | awk '{print $NF}'
```

I need the output of this command to go to a new file called NEW.txt

So i did this :

```
$awk 'NR>2' IMSI.txt | awk '{print $NF}' > NEW.txt
```

This worked fine, but when i open the file, the output from the command are on the same line.
The new line is being neglected.

As an example, if i get an output in the console

```
222
111
333
```

i open the text file and i get

```
222111333
```

How can i fix that ?

Thank you for your help :)

PS: i am using Cygwin on windows

Comment: Can you post `IMSI.txt`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing your (Windows-y) editor would like to see Carriage Returns at the end of lines, not Linefeeds (which is what `awk` outputs). Change your `print` to this

```
print $NF "\r"
```

so it looks like this altogether:

```
awk 'NR>2 {print $NF "\r"}' IMSI.txt
```

Comment: Indeed, I believe `Wordpad` can handle Unix-y linefeeds, whereas `Notepad` cannot. However, I am not saying either is a good editor :-)

Comment: Excellent! Glad to be of service. Note that if your `awk` program was more complicated, and contained more than a couple of `print` statements, @konsolebox's method would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Simply set your ORS to `"\r\n"` which allows Awk to generate DOS line endings for every output. I believe this is the most natural solution:

```
awk -v ORS="\r\n" '{print $NF}' > NEW.txt
```

Tested on a virtual XP system with Cygwin.

From Awk's manual:

> **ORS**    The output record separator, by default a newline.